# AWS service endpoint region vs. signing region

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it at all possible to invoke an AWS service whose endpoint is in a region other than the one hosting my account?

For instance, my account is in us-west-1 and SES has been removed from that region. Can I somehow invoke the SES service from us-west-2? When creating a request to send an email I cannot seem to find a way to set the service endpoint region that does not also set the signing region.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, yes. The class EndpointConfiguration allows that.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration.html